# How to add Cors to PostGraphile

Tags: node.js, express, cors, postgraphile

I am trying to add cors to my PostGraphile route in an express server.

```
app.use(
  postgraphile(process.env.DATABASE_URL || process.env.POSTGRES, ‘public’, {
  watchPg: true,
  graphiql: true,
  enhanceGraphiql: true,
  enableCors: true,
  }),
);
```

When I am trying to call the route from postmen I get * (wildcard) in Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

How do I add specific routes to return by Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [cors](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) middleware before the postgraphile and set the origin in the options:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const { postgraphile } = require('postgraphile');

const options = {
    origin: 'https://your_origin',
};

app.use(cors(options));

// Enable pre-flight requests for all routes
app.options('*', cors(options));

app.use(
    postgraphile(process.env.DATABASE_URL || process.env.POSTGRES, ‘public’, {
    watchPg: true,
    graphiql: true,
    enhanceGraphiql: true,
    }),
);
```

this will set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `https://your_origin`